# Can beautiful soup give a chuck of file based on span class=?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some simple fields from an HTML page.  It is a table with some repetitive data.

Every record has a FIRST_NAME (and a bunch of other stuff) but not every record has a WEBSITE.  So my xpath solution was returning 10 names but only 9 website urls.

```
fname= tree.xpath('//span[@class="given-name"]/text()')
fweb = tree.xpath('//a[@class="url"]/text()')
```

Using that method I can't tell which record is missing the url.

So now I want to divide the file into chunks; each chunk would start with the span class GIVEN-NAME and end right before the next GIVEN-NAME.

How do I do that?  In my code, I have an infinite loop that keeps returning the first instance of span class FIRST-NAME, it doesn't progress through the HTML file.

```
with open('sample A.htm') as f:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f.read())

    many_names= soup.find_all('span',class_='given-name')
    print len(many_names)

    for i in range(len(many_names)):
        first_name = soup.find('span', class_='given-name').text 
        website = soup.find('a', class_='url').text
        myprint (i, first_name, last_name, aco, city, qm, website)
        soup.find_next('span', class_='given-name')
```

The last statement (find_next) doesn't seem to do anything.

With or without it, it's just loop that reads from the beginning over and over again.  What is the right way to do this?

EDIT:  sample from HTML file (I edited some out because there is a lot more)
Physically, the layout is span **given-name** blah blah blah **URL** buried in there somewhere, then another span **given-name**

```
enter code here
</div>

<div class="connections-list cn-list-body cn-clear" id="cn-list-body">
<div class="cn-list-section-head" id="cn-char-A"></div><div class="cn-list-row-alternate vcard individual art-literary-agents celebrity-nonfiction-literary-agents chick-lit-fiction-literary-agents commercial-fiction-literary-agents fiction-literary-agents film-entertainment-literary-agents history-nonfiction-literary-agents literary-fiction-literary-agents military-war-literary-agents multicultural-nonfiction-literary-agents multicultural-fiction-literary-agents music-literary-agents new-york-literary-agents-ny nonfiction-literary-agents photography-literary-agents pop-culture-literary-agents religion-nonfiction-literary-agents short-story-collection-literary-agents spirituality-literary-agents sports-nonfiction-literary-agents usa-literary-agents womens-issues-literary-agents" id="richard-abate" data-entry-type="individual" data-entry-id="19337" data-entry-slug="richard-abate"><div id="entry-id-193375501ffd6551a6" class="cn-entry">
    <table border="0px" bordercolor="#E3E3E3" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="55%" valign="top">

<span class="cn-image-style"><span style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 125px"><img height="125" width="125" sizes="100vw" class="cn-image logo" alt="Logo for Richard Abate" title="Logo for Richard Abate" srcset="http://literaryagencies.com/wp-content/uploads/connections-images/richard-abate/richard-abate-literary-agent_logo_1-7bbdb1a0dbafe8417e994150608c55e4.jpg 1x" /></span></span>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="top" style="text-align: right;">

                <div style="clear:both; margin: 5px 5px;">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

<span class="fn n"> <span class="given-name">Richard</span> <span class="family-name">Abate</span> </span>

<span class="title">3 Arts Entertainment</span>

<span class="org"><span class="organization-unit">Query method(s): Postal Mail *</span></span>
                                            </div>


<span class="address-block">
<span class="adr"><span class="address-name">Work</span> <span class="street-address">16 West 22th St</span> <span class="locality">New York</span> <span class="region">NY</span> <span class="postal-code">10010</span> <span class="country-name">USA</span><span class="type" style="display: none;">work</span></span>
</span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign="bottom" style="text-align: left;">

                <a class="cn-note-anchor toggle-div" id="note-anchor-193375501ffd6551a6" href="#" data-uuid="193375501ffd6551a6" data-div-id="note-block-193375501ffd6551a6" data-str-show="Show Notes" data-str-hide="Close Notes">Show Notes</a> | <a class="cn-bio-anchor toggle-div" id="bio-anchor-193375501ffd6551a6" href="#" data-uuid="193375501ffd6551a6" data-div-id="bio-block-193375501ffd6551a6" data-str-show="Show Bio" data-str-hide="Close Bio">Show Bio</a>              
            </td>

            <td align="right" valign="bottom"  style="text-align: right;">

                <a class="url" href="http://www.3arts.com" target="new" rel="nofollow">http://www.3arts.com</a>


<span class="cn-image-style"><span style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 125px"><img height="125" width="125" sizes="100vw" class="cn-image logo" alt="Logo for Andree Abecassis" title="Logo for Andree Abecassis" srcset="http://literaryagencies.com/wp-content/uploads/connections-images/andree-abecassis/andree-abecassis-literary-agent_logo_1-b531cbac02864497b301e74bc6b37aa9.jpg 1x" /></span></span>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="top" style="text-align: right;">

                <div style="clear:both; margin: 5px 5px;">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

<span class="fn n"> <span class="given-name">Andree</span> <span class="family-name">Abecassis</span> </span>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's **not** the case, assuming you're properly copied and pasted your code, that the last statement gives you a `SyntaxError` as you say; rather it will give you an `AttributeError` because you've mis-spelled the method name `findNext` calling it, instead, `find_next` for some mysterious reason.  In general, **copy and paste your traceback** rather than trying to "paraphrase" it.

However, since you already have a list of all the spans with the relevant class, simplest is to change your second loop to search within each of them:

```
for i, a_span in enumerate(many_names):
    first_name = a_span.text 
    website = a_span.find('a', class_='url')
    if website is None:
        website = '*MISSING*'
    else:
        website = website.text
    last_name = aco = city = qm = 'YOU NEVER EXTRACT THESE!!!'
    myprint(i, first_name, last_name, aco, city, qm, website)
```

assuming you have indeed defined a function `myprint` with all of these parameters.

You'll note I've set four variables to remind you that you never extract these values -- I suspect you'll want to **fix** that, right?-)

EDIT: as it now appears the relation between the tags being sought is **not** in the HTML's structure, but a fragile dependence on the mere **sequence** of the tags' occurrence in the HTML text, a very different approach is required.  Here's a possibility:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('ha.txt') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

def tag_of_interest(t):
    if t.name=='a': return t.attrs.get('class')==['url']
    if t.name=='span': return t.attrs.get('class')==['given-name']
    return False

for t in soup.find_all(tag_of_interest):
    print(t)
```

E.g, when I save in `ha.txt` the HTML snippet now given in the Q after an edit, this script emits:

```
<span class="given-name">Richard</span>
<a class="url" href="http://www.3arts.com" rel="nofollow" target="new">http://www.3arts.com</a>
<span class="given-name">Andree</span>
```

So what now remains is to appropriately **group** the relevant sequence of tags (which I think will also include others, such as the spans with class `last-name` &c).  A `class` seems appropriate (and functionality such as `myprint` could neatly be recast as methods of the class, but I'll skip that part).

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.first_name = self.last_name = self.website = None  # &c

entities = []

for t in soup.find_all(tag_of_interest):
    if t.name=='span' and t.class==['given-name']:
        ent = Entity()
        ent.given-name = t.text
        entities.append(ent)
    else:
        if not entities:
            print 'tag', t, 'out of context'
            continue
        ent = entities[-1]
        if t.name=='a' and t.class==['url']:
            ent.website = t.text
        # etc for other tags of interest
```

In the end, the `entities` list can be examined for entities missing mandatory bits of data, and so forth.

Comment: On the extra variables, yes I have them, I just edited them out because they don't add anything to my question.  But  you are right.

Comment: Another thing you are right about, it was not a syntax error!  Now I must read your code and see if I can understand it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't upvote right now, but when I get enough rep I will come back.

Comment: @VeeLa, you're welcome and thanks!, and welcome to our StackOverflow community where I look forward to see you become an active participant!

Comment: **website.text** is not a valid thing:      
**Traceback (most recent call last):**
website = a_span.find('a',class_='url').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I wondered about that.  

But now even the ones that are there are coming up as MISSING. e.g. (in fact all 10 are missing; there should be only 1 missing)

1 ,  Richard TBD ,  TBD ,  TBD ,  TBD ,  *MISSING!*
2 ,  Andree TBD ,  TBD ,  TBD ,  TBD ,  *MISSING!*
3 ,  Dominick TBD ,  TBD ,  TBD ,  TBD ,  *MISSING!*


something else is wrong with the url lookup

Comment: @VeeLa so it looks like the `a` tags you're looking for are **not** nested within those respective `span` tags.  Hard to debug this w/o seeing a relevant snippet of the HTML in question, so can you edit your Q to show such a snipper with a couple of the relevant `span`s and `a`s and whatever's in-between...?  (I.e is there a common parent tag to both, or how else is the span/a correspondence to be established...?)

Comment: OK, I added to bottom.  Hope it is not too much to ask.

Comment: @VeeLa OK, edited my A to provide the completely different approach needed to scrape that mess of an HTML.

Comment: OMG.  I will try to read and understand.  It could take days.  Thank you so much for your help.  Is Soup the wrong way to tackle this?  Or is this just the normal kind of things you run in to with scraping?  I was really happy with xpath because it seemed to ignore all the mess.

Comment: @VeeLa, your choice, of course -- but how do you get xpath to give you all kinds of tags you need in strict sequential order?  It may "ignore the mess" but if so you apparently **can't afford to** since the sequential mess (without the proper structure) appears to be crucial to your never-clearly-expressed goal! BeautifulSoup acknowledges the typical HTML messes and lets you **deal** with them -- would you rather actually handle the mess you're dealt, and end up with a terrible hack that does work, or would you rather ignore it, and never achieve your goal?

Comment: Alex, you've really done a lot here.  My goal is not too difficult.  I just want the name and website pairs if I can get them.  There are so many things I don't know.   Anyway.  My simplistic idea was to create a context or a mini-html snippet that encompassed one name to the next; and then operate within that context.  I thought I could find the url within there or if not then go on to the next.    I used to write small things like this in AWK where this approach would be much easier.  Probably not a good transferable way of thinking in this case.  Thank you again and again for yr kindness.